# Testing DDS reader receiving message for java unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service

I have a unit test in which I am able to test sending `DDS` messages currently. However, I **also** want to implement the ability to test the message readers as well.

The problem is, due to the programs setup for creation of DDS readers and writers. If I try to make the readers I need, they already have the same `topic` as the writer and due to this an exception is thrown.

Has anyone thus figured out a way to simulate sending DDS messages to a reader as if they came from a DDS writer? Within one computer and no using separate computers on a network to do so.

Comment: Which DDS implementation do you use? And which call exactly throws the exception?

Comment: RTI and create topic, since the topics are already created due to how my implementation works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lookup_topicdescription()`](https://community.rti.com/rti-doc/510/ndds.5.1.0/doc/html/api_java/interfacecom_1_1rti_1_1dds_1_1domain_1_1DomainParticipant.html#a994606ac144363cffa858579f5cd9b6f) on the `DomainParticipant` to get a reference to the previously created `Topic`, if it exists. In pseudo-code, you could do something like

```
use lookup_topicdescription() to see if topic exists
if topic does not exist
  use create_topic() to create the topic
```

If your application does this in multiple threads, then you will have to grab and release a lock around this code.